# Error of unsupported operand type for: str and int even though the type is str and str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am reading data table from pdf and storing it in 2 arrays, `dates = [1997, 1998]` and `prices = [3.45, 2.10, 1.89, ...]`  then I am formatting the dates in storing it in the dictionary as `'1997,01', '1997,02'...` and the Values accordingly. In the end I will send the

I am having problem with `ex1_b(date: str)` function where I try to change the date format to year-month. For example when I pass to the function  `"1997,01"` it should return `1997-Dec`

It gives out an error that I am trying to add str with int, but when I checked what type the `years` and `months` returns inside the function, it returns str.
So I don't understand what I am doing wrong

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\trypdf.py", line 55, in <module>
    ex1_b("2000,02")
  File "c:\Users\User\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\trypdf.py", line 51, in ex1_b
    date_form = str(years) + "-" + str(mon[months-1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I solve this?

My code:

```
# THE BEGINNING IN CASE IT IS IMPORTANT

import PyPDF2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pdf = (open("hw.pdf", "rb"))
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf)
page_object = pdfReader.getPage(4)
text = page_object.extractText()
splitted_text = text.split()

dates = []
prices = []

for i in range(4, len(splitted_text)):
    if float(splitted_text[i]) < 1997:
        prices.append(float(splitted_text[i]))
    else:
        dates.append(int(splitted_text[i]))
pdf.close()

df = {'Date' : [],
      'Values' : []}

for i in range(0, 25):
    for j in range(0, 12):
        month = str(j+1).zfill(2)
        df['Date'].append( str(dates[i]) + "," + month)
        
for i in range(0,300):
    df['Values'].append(prices[i])

print(df)

mon = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

date_form = []

# THE PROBLEM
def ex1_b(date: str):

    years =  str(date.split(",")[0])
    months = str(date.split(",")[1])

    date_form = str(years) + "-" + str(mon[months-1])

    return date_form
ex1_b("2000,02")
```

Comment: Python doesn't lie about this kind of thing. When you see errors like this, it's not reasonable to expect that the error is on Python's side; asserting "even though the type is str and str" just isn't going to be True

Comment: The line in the traceback, `date_form = years + "-" + mon[months-1]`, is different than the line in code. You are running something different than you think.

Comment: Its common to use an f-string for this. You can add expressions in curly braces and python automatically calls 'str' for you. `date_form = f"{years}-{mon[months-1]}"`

Comment: @tdelaney it still gives out the same error

Comment: @roganjosh but I am changing the type each type str() why it still gives out an error

Comment: No you're not. Compare the traceback to your actual code

Comment: There was another problem - `months` is a string, so `months-1` doesn't work.

Comment: ` + "-" +` isn't trying to subtract anything.  `months-1` is trying to subtract an `int` from something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following line, the value of the variable "months" is a string. Not an integer.

```
months = str(date.split(",")[1])
```

Later you subtracted 1 from the string month like this.

```
mon[months-1]
```

You can't use subtract operand with a string and an integer. Convert the variable "months" to an integer before subtracting 1.

ex:
`mon[int(months)-1]`